# assigning localdate variable to another variable and store it database

Tags: javascript, date, time, field

Am trying to get the date field in a html form using Date input.The default date value is in the yyyy-mm-dd format. I changed the format to dd-mm-yyyy using JavaScript. When i assign the changed format date to the another variable and try to save it..it gets saved in the default format.plz help

Am trying to get the date field in a html form using Date input.The default date value is in the yyyy-mm-dd format. I changed the format to dd-mm-yyyy using JavaScript. When I assign the changed format date to the another variable and try to save it..it gets saved in the default format

html

```
    <td  align="left" nowrap >
            Date
    </td>

    <td align="left">
                        <input id="to" type="datetime-local" name="to"  value="<%=stdt%>"  min="00:00:0000" max="00:00:0000"  required>

                    </td>

var now = new Date();
var utcString = now.toISOString().substring(0,19);
var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var day = now.getDate();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
var second = now.getSeconds();
var localDatetime = 
    (day < 10 ? "0" + day.toString() : day) + "-" +
    (month < 10 ? "0" + month.toString() : month) + "-" +
    year + " " +
    //(day < 10 ? "0" + day.toString() : day) + "T" +
    (hour < 10 ? "0" + hour.toString() : hour) + ":" +
    (minute < 10 ? "0" + minute.toString() : minute) +
    utcString.substring(16,19);


        alert(localDatetime);
    var to = document.getElementById("to");
    to.value = localDatetime;
```

the alert command correctly displays the changed format dd-mm-yyyy.But when this value is assigned to the variable "to" and try to save it..it gets saved as the default format yyyy-mm-dd.Not sure where i am going wrong.s

Comment: An input using `type="datetime-local"` only supports the ISO date format. It can *convert* some other date formats to the ISO format, but it will convert them, it won't preserve your own different formatting.

Comment: By the way, you can convert those many lines of code to convert the date format to this: `var parts = /(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T([^.]*)/.exec(new Date().toISOString()); var localDateTime = parts[3] + '-' + parts[2] + '-' + parts[1] + ' ' + parts[4];`

Comment: Hi @Kshetline replaced the code as you said  as below..but still not getting the desired o/pvar now = new Date();
var utcString = now.toISOString().substring(0,19);
var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var day = now.getDate();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
var second = now.getSeconds();

 var parts = /(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T([^.]*)/.exec(new Date().toISOString()); 
var localDateTime = parts[3] + '-' + parts[2] + '-' + parts[1] + ' ' + parts[4];
 alert(localDatetime);
 document.forms["myform1"].to.value = localDatetime;

Comment: I suggested that code only as a side comment, not as a solution to your primary issue. My first comment still stands -- there basically isn't a solution to that problem. If you want an input field that uses a date in a different format, you'll just have to use an ordinary `type="text"` input, and then all of the work for enforcing min/max dates, etc. will be on you.

Comment: You also missed part of the point of my side comment -- you don't need this whole block of code: `var now = new Date();
var utcString = now.toISOString().substring(0,19);
var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
var day = now.getDate();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
var second = now.getSeconds();` *For the purpose of formatting the date* alone -- NOT for making the input field work they way you want, you don't need to do all of that to format the date.

Comment: "JavaScript" not "java script".  http://javascriptisnotjava.com/. Space after periods in a new sentence. Please take more care in typing. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat site.